# is this function increasing or decreasing on what intervals?

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I have the probability density function for $X$ is $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{\dfrac{-(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$. Let $R=D(X)=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$ and $-\infty<x<\infty,-\infty<\mu<\infty,\sigma>0 $. Now I have to find the probability density function of $R$. But the issue I'm having is finding on what intervals is R increasing, decreasing, and constant. I know that $R'=\frac{1}{\sigma}>0$ which means its increasing on $(-\infty,\infty)$. I assume that $\mu, \sigma$ are constants since $\mu=mean$ and $\sigma=standard deviation$ of a normal distribution. I don't think what I have is right.

Comment: Do you mean $R = \frac{X - \mu}{\sigma}$? And what is $X$? Is it the random variable with the density you start off the question with?

Comment: Well R is a function.  And yes $f(x)$ is the probability function for $X$.

Answer (score 0):

$R$ is a random variable, since it is a function of the random variable $X$. Unless the sample space is also $\Bbb{R}$, it doesn't make sense to ask on what intervals $R$ is increasing/decreasing/etc.

To find the density of $R$, I suggest the following hint:

$$
F_R(x) = P(R \leq x) = P\Big( \frac{X-\mu}{\sigma} \leq x\Big) = P\Big( X \leq \sigma x + \mu\Big) = F_X(\sigma x + \mu)
$$
where $F_R$ and $F_X$ are the CDFs of $R$ and $X$. Now, the density of $R$ is given by 
$$
f_R(x) = \frac{d}{dx}F_R(x) = \frac{d}{dx}F_X(\sigma x + \mu) = \cdots
$$